# Numerically stable way to calculate normal log likelihood

Tags: java, numeric

I am trying to calculate the normal log likelihood which is given by:

```
L = l1+l2+l3+...+ln,
```

where

```
lk = log(1/(sqrt(2*PI)*sigma_k))-0.5*e_k*e_k
```

Sigmas are around `0.2`, and `e_k` are normally distributed with mean 0 and unit variance, so most of them are between -2 and 2;

I tried the following java code (sigma_k mentioned above = sigmas.get(k)*Math.sqrt(dt)):

```
private double new1(List<Double> residuals, List<Double> sigmas, double dt) {
    double a = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<sigmas.size(); i++) {
        a += Math.log(1.0/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI*dt)*sigmas.get(i)));
    }
    double b = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<residuals.size(); i++) {
        b += residuals.get(i)*residuals.get(i);
    }
    return a-0.5*b;
}
```

but the theoretical maximum is lower than the maximum I got by doing numerical optimisation, so I have some suspicions that my method is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark:**
In some areas probability/statistics are calculated without taking the **log**, for instance in linguistic frequencies of combinations.

The following simplifies, becoming less stable, but afterwards one convert it back to a sum of logs or so.

---

```
double a = 0;
for(int i=0; i<sigmas.size(); i++) {
    a += Math.log(1.0/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI*dt)*sigmas.get(i)));
}
```

---

**log(x) + log(y) = log(x*y)**

```
double a = 1.0;
for(int i=0; i<sigmas.size(); i++) {
    a *= 1.0/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI*dt)*sigmas.get(i));
}
a = Math.log(a);
```

---

**(1/x)*(1/y) = 1/(x*y)**

```
double a = 1.0;
for(int i=0; i<sigmas.size(); i++) {
    a *= Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI*dt)*sigmas.get(i);
}
a = Math.log(1.0/a);
```

---

**sqrt(x)^n = (x^0.5)^n = x^(n/2)**

```
static import Math.*;

double a = pow(2*PI*dt, sigmas.size() / 2.0);
for(int i=0; i<sigmas.size(); i++) {
    a *= sigmas.get(i);
}
a = -log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will greatly improve numerical stability, but your equations can be simplified using logarithm laws:

```
log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)
log(1/a) = -log(a)
log(sqrt(a)) = log(a)/2
```

so you have:

```
lk = -log(2*pi)/2 - log(sigma_k) - 0.5*e_k*e_k
   = -log(2*pi)/2 - log(dt)/2 - log(sigmas.get(k)) - 0.5*e_k*e_k
   = -log(2*pi*dt)/2 - log(sigmas.get(k)) - 0.5*e_k*e_k
```

First is constant, so in the first loop you only need to do `a -= log(sigmas.get(k))`.

Also, it look suspicious, that first loop is to `sigmas.size()` and the second to `residuals.size()` while the equation suggests, that they should have the same length.